# Jed versus jeweils

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "jed" and "jeweils"? I am under the impression that they both mean "each." One of the bigger difference that I have noticed is that "jeweils" is never conjugated.

Comment: **jed…** is not a word but only the beginning of a number of words. Which one of those do you mean? Or do you mean **je**?

Comment: I mean "jed" in the sense that it takes on an ending depending on the noun that it is referring to, such as "jedes," "jede" or "jedem."

Comment: *Jeder/jede/jedes* and *jeweils* have nothing in common but the beginning letters *je* and a broad relation to the word *je* itself.

Comment: I think that "je" is just short for "jeweils." And "jed" and "jeweils" are somehow similar in their meaning.

Comment: To answer the question about **jeweils**, it usually does **not** translate into *each* but **each with**.

Comment: Are you saying that "jeweils" is more along the lines of the words "per" and "pro"?

Comment: *Jeweils* is the complement of *pro/je*. *Nehmen Sie bitte **jeweils** eine Tablette **je** Mahlzeit.*

Comment: "each with"? What is that supposed to be, @Janka?

Comment: @user109871 Only verbs are conjugated. Adjectives and nouns are declined. "Jeweils" is an adverb, so it cannot be declined or conjugated. "Jed" is the beginning of many adverbs, "jedermann", "jedoch", "jeder", "jedenfalls", plus many many more. There's no specific difference to tell because it's for one not clear what you're looking for, and for another a dictionary is good way to start.

Comment: @Em1: I meant to emphasize the difference to *each one* (jeder/jede/jedes).

Comment: Note that German speakers (or probably speakers of any language) will not generally recognise what you are talking about if you just use a word stem (like "jed") for a set of whole words (like "jeder/jede/jedes"). I thought "jed" in the title was just a typo, for example, so I suggest editing your question so it becomes clear what it is you're asking.

Comment: To give you an example you might intuitvely relate to, suppose someone came to you and asked what the difference between "bet" and "superior" is in English.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "jeder/jede/jedes" because "jed" doesn't exist.

I try to explain it with some examples:

Jeder bekommt eine Tafel Schokolade. Everybody gets a bar of chocolate.

Die Teilnehmer bekommen jeweils eine Tafel Schokolade. Each participant gets a bar of chocolate.

So, "jeder" can be translated with "everybody" while "jeweils" means "each". I don't think that there is a bigger difference in normal conversations so you can use both "jeder" and "jeweils".

Answer (score 1):

The word *jeweils* translates, as you correctly noticed, to *each* or *each of*. But it may also be translated to *always*, as in

> Er wählte *jeweils* zwei pro Kategorie.

which means

> He selected *always* two per category.

The words *jeder/jede/jedes* translate to *every* or, depending on the context, to *everybody/everyone*. The word stem *jed* does not form a german word by itself.